# PHP/MySQL: Simple timekeeping and update scheme?

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to use PHP to fetch content from a MySQL database once per day, at time *T*. There will be several users logged into the server, and the update may happen while one or more are logged in.

What would be a good way to keep time here and silently update so that users will see the update when they log out and log back in again? This is my initial idea, but there's likely a faster and better way.... Any suggestions?

Proposal:

```
now = php_timekeeping_function(); // seconds
if ((T - now) % SECONDS_IN_A_DAY == 0) content = update_content_with_SQL_query();
display(content);
```

Comment: Are `now`, `T` and `content` variables? Then they should begin with `$`.

Comment: You should go with running a cron job. You may find more about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239985/php-mysql-simple-timekeeping-and-update-scheme#autocomment31995352

Comment: That would be pseudocode ;)

Comment: So the sticking point here is in trying to not show updates while an individual user is logged in.  This adds complexity to the situation.  Is this an absolute requirement, because, if not, a simple cron to make DB updates would seem to be the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is using a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). That way you can be sure that it runs.